# Removing all strings except specific except some in Regex

Tags: regex

I have tried to find the solution of this problem, but I still can't get the correct answer. Therefore, I decided to ask you all here for help. 
**I have some text :**

> CommentTimestamps:true,showVODCommentTimestamps:false,enableVODStreamingComments:false,enablePinLiveComments:false,enableFacecastAnimatedComments:false,permalink:"1",isViewerTheOwner:false,isLiveAudio:false,mentionsinput:{inputComponent:{__m:"LegacyMentionsInput.react"}},monitorHeight:false,viewoptionstypeobjects:null,viewoptionstypeobjectsorder:null,addcommentautoflip:true,autoplayLiveVODComments:true,disableCSSHiding:true,feedbackMode:"none",instanceid:"u_0_w",lazyFetch:true,numLazyComments:2,pagesize:50,postViewCount:"78,762",shortenTimestamp:true,showaddcomment:true,showshares:true,totalPosts:1,viewCount:"78,762",viewCountReduced:"78K"},{comments:[],pinnedcomments:[],profiles:{},actions:[],commentlists:{comments:{"1":{filtered:{range:{offset:32,length:0},values:[],count:32,clienthasall:false}}},replies:null},featuredcommentlists:{comments:null,replies:null},featuredcommentids:null,servertime:1492916773,feedb.........`

What I want to get is only : **`postViewCount:"78,762"`**

I have tried using `[^(postViewCount\b.......)]` but it is not what I want to get.

Comment: Try `postViewCount:"(?:.*?)"` ... but what tool language are you using?

Comment: Do you just want to match?  Or do you want to replace or maybe extract?

Comment: It now matches, and I want to replace other string except postViewCount:"78,762". Thank you so much!

Comment: Then show your expected output as well.

Comment: Others needs to be removed, but postViewCount:"78,762" does not :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This should do it*

***`(postViewCount:\"\d{2}\,\d{3}\")`***

***https://regex101.com/r/9JENH0/1***

[image]

***`postViewCount:`*** matches the characters postViewCount: literally (case sensitive)
**`\"`** matches the character **`"`** literally (case sensitive)
**`\d{2}`** matches a digit (`equal to [0-9]`) **`{2}`** Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times 
**`\,`** matches the character **`,`** literally (case sensitive)

---

Now if the count is one million or larger then use ***`(postViewCount:"(?:.*?)")`***

---

Comment: What happens if the post count is say one million or larger?

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen then your example will work better. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Regex:** `postViewCount:"[^"]+"`

> **1.** `postViewCount:"` will match `postViewCount:"`
>
> **2.** `[^"]+` match all till `"`

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/n9g8IO/1)

Answer (score 0):

try to match -

> .*(postViewCount:"[0-9,]*").*
>   and replace it with catched group that is \1

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/CENGCm/2/)